# Calling Terraform from Azure ARM

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-rm-template

Is there any way to call Terraform scritps from Azure ARM? like ARM allows to call other ARM templates.

Scenario is this:

We have ARM templates which create these Infra services(VM, Load balance) to our apps.  We have decided to use Terraform to do the same.

We still want to use Azure ARM to capture the inputs and somehow pass these inputs to Terraform and execute Terraform scripts.

Any thoughts will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This is not exactly true, you can [call terraform from ARM Templates](https://azure.microsoft.com/nl-nl/blog/introducing-the-azure-terraform-resource-provider/), but in general I'd suggest against doing that. There are number of other ways you can implement that and calling terraform directly would be a much better option.

Also, if you are aiming at using terraform, would probably be better to refactor ARM Templates into terraform configurations, else terraform is kinda useless (well, its, kinda, always useless, but its a whole different story).

Comment: You can where needed call ARM Templates from Terraform, but I 100% agree with this answer. 
https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/template_deployment.html

Comment: @4c74356b41 why is it kinda useless? :)

Answer (score 0):

No. Terraform scripts need an engine to be processed. ARM (the Azure Resource Manager) is no such engine for TF.

You could build, however, a CD pipeline, e.g. in Azure DevOps. In one task you use ARM template, and pass the outputs into the next Terraform task.